# Unity: change splash screen logo sprite programmatically

Tags: unity-game-engine

We are making different builds of our game for multiple platforms using conditional compilation. And for some platforms we need to set a different logo image. Is there a way to do it from scripts in a suchlike way:

```
#if (PLATFORM_VARIABLE)
        PlayerSettings.SplashScreen.logos[0].logo = developerLogo;
#else
        PlayerSettings.SplashScreen.logos[0].logo = publisherLogo;
#endif
```

Comment: I would claim yes .. have you tried it this way?

Comment: Note that `PlayerSettings.virtualRealitySplashScreen` is a different one

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.
Here, they are dynamically loading the Sprite and assigning it.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.SplashScreen-logos.html